# CUDA - Same algorithm works on CPU but not on GPU

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am currently working on my first project in CUDA and I ran into something odd, that must be inherent to CUDA and that I don't understand or have overlooked. The same algorithm - the exact same one really, it involves no parallel work - works on the CPU but not on the GPU.

Let me explain in more detail. I am doing thresholding using [Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method) duplicates computation but reduces transfer time. Short story long, this function:

```
__device__ double computeThreshold(unsigned int* histogram, int* nbPixels){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        sum += i*histogram[i];
    }
    int sumB = 0, wB = 0, wF = 0;
    double mB, mF, max = 1, between = 0, threshold1 = 0, threshold2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 256 && !(wF == 0 && j != 0 && wB != 0); j++){
        wB += histogram[j];
        if (wB != 0) {
            wF = *nbPixels - wB;
            if (wF != 0){
                sumB += j*histogram[i];
                mB = sumB / wB;
                mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;
                between = wB * wF *(mB - mF) *(mB - mF);
                if (max < 2.0){
                    threshold1 = j;
                    if (between > max){
                        threshold2 = j;
                    }
                    max = between;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (threshold1 + threshold2) / 2.0;
}
```

This works as expected for an image size (ie number of pixels) not too big but fails otherwise; interestingly, even if I don't use `histogram` and `nbPixels` in the function and replace all their occurrences by a constant, it still fails - even if I remove the arguments from the function.  (What I mean by fail is that the first operation after the call to the kernel returns an unspecified launch failure.)

EDIT 3: Ok, there was a small mistake due to copy/paste errors in what I provided before to test. Now this compiles and allows to reproduce the error:

```
__device__ double computeThreshold(unsigned int* histogram, long int* nbPixels){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        sum += i*histogram[i];
    }
    int sumB = 0, wB = 0, wF = 0;
    double mB, mF, max = 1, between = 0, threshold1 = 0, threshold2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 256 && !(wF == 0 && j != 0 && wB != 0); j++){
        wB += histogram[j];
        if (wB != 0) {
            wF = *nbPixels - wB;
            if (wF != 0){
                sumB += j*histogram[j];
                mB = sumB / wB;
                mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;
                between = wB * wF *(mB - mF) *(mB - mF);
                if (max < 2.0){
                    threshold1 = j;
                    if (between > max){
                        threshold2 = j;
                    }
                    max = between;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (threshold1 + threshold2) / 2.0;
}

__global__ void imageKernel(unsigned int* image, unsigned int* histogram, long int* nbPixels, double* t_threshold){

    unsigned int i = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    if (i >= *nbPixels) return;
    double threshold = computeThreshold(histogram, nbPixels);
    unsigned int pixel = image[i];
    if (pixel >= threshold){
        pixel = 255;
    } else {
        pixel = 0;
    }
    image[i] = pixel;

    *t_threshold = threshold;

}


int main(){
unsigned int histogram[256] = { 0 };
const int width = 2048 * 4096;
const int height = 1;

unsigned int* myimage;
myimage = new unsigned int[width*height];
for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++){
    myimage[i] = i % 256;
    histogram[i % 256]++;
}
const int threadPerBlock = 256;
const int nbBlock = ceil((double)(width*height) / threadPerBlock);
unsigned int* partial_histograms = new unsigned int[256 * nbBlock];

dim3 dimBlock(threadPerBlock, 1);
dim3 dimGrid(nbBlock, 1);
unsigned int* dev_image;
unsigned int* dev_histogram;
unsigned int* dev_partial_histograms;
double* dev_threshold;
double x = 0;
double* threshold = &x;
long int* nbPixels;
long int nb = width*height;
nbPixels = &(nb);
long int* dev_nbPixels;

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_image, sizeof(unsigned int)*width*height);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_histogram, sizeof(unsigned int)* 256);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_partial_histograms, sizeof(unsigned int)* 256 * nbBlock);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_threshold, sizeof(double));
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_nbPixels, sizeof(long int));
cudaMemcpy(dev_image, myimage, sizeof(unsigned int)*width*height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_histogram, histogram, sizeof(unsigned int)* 256, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_nbPixels, nbPixels, sizeof(long int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);





imageKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_image, dev_histogram, dev_nbPixels, dev_threshold);



cudaMemcpy(histogram, dev_histogram, sizeof(unsigned int)* 256, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(partial_histograms, dev_partial_histograms, sizeof(unsigned int)* 256 * nbBlock, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(threshold, dev_threshold, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaDeviceReset();


return 0;
}
```

EDIT 4: the characteristics of my GPU

```
 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 750M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147483648 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1085 MHz (1.09 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 262144 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536),
3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Mo
del)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simu
ltaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Versi
on = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GT 750M
Result = PASS
```

EDIT 5: I ran cuda-memcheck again and this time, it did output an error message. I don't know why it didn't the first time, I must have done something wrong again. I hope you will pardon me those hesitations and wastes of time. Here is the output message:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launc
h failure" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xb780
2) [0xdb1e2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0x160f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xc764]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xfe24]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk +
 0x22) [0x13d2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x3
4) [0x15454]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launc
h failure" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xb780
2) [0xdb1e2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0x160f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xc788]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xfe24]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk +
 0x22) [0x13d2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x3
4) [0x15454]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launc
h failure" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xb780
2) [0xdb1e2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0x160f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xc7a6]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Nicolas\Cours\3PC\test.exe [0xfe24]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk +
 0x22) [0x13d2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x3
4) [0x15454]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors
```

Not very telling though, is it ?

Comment: You need to supply the host code.

Comment: In this sort of debugging question, unless you can supply the shortest, complete code which someone else could copy and paste into an editor, compile and run, and which reproduces your error, we can't help you. CUDA ships with tools like cuda-memcheck for detecting memory access errors. Have you tried using them?

Comment: @talonmies I know it's hard - if not impossible - to find the error just like this, but I figured that maybe there was a relatively basic principle that I might have overlooked. I tried cuda-memcheck, yes, and it didn't find any error.

Comment: @Nico: there probably is a basic principle that you have overlooked. But I can't tell you what that is without code I can analyse. And I can't analyse what you have posted. There are too many undefined variables for that.

Comment: @talonmies here, I added a main method to run the code. I think nothing is missing to make it runnable but if so, please tell me.

Comment: It doesn't compile. The device has an undefined variable in it and the kernel passes an incorrect argument into the device function. If you are trying to waste the time of those trying to help you, you are doing a pretty good job of it.

Comment: @talonmies right. Very sorry about that, now I checked and it does.

Comment: I compiled with nvcc 7.5. Runs without errors on a GTX680... Can you give details about your environment?

Comment: You might be running into a Windows TDR timeout.

Comment: @RobertCrovella YES! Thank you so much good sir, I would never have found this out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out it wasn't an error of my side but Windows deciding that 2s was enough and that it needed to reset the GPU - stopping there my computation. Thanks a lot to @RobertCrovella, without whom I would never have found this out. And thanks to everyone who tried to answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

So after providing a compileable example (was it *really* so hard?), I can't reproduce any errors with this code (64 bit linux, compute 3.0 device, CUDA 7.0 release version):

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -Xptxas="-v" histogram.cu 
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z11imageKernelPjS_PlPd' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z11imageKernelPjS_PlPd
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 34 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0], 16 bytes cmem[2]

$ for i in `seq 1 20`;
> do
>     cuda-memcheck ./a.out
> done
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

So if you can reproduce a runtime error doing as I have done, your environment/hardware/toolkit version are subtly different in some way from mine. But in any case the code itself works, and you have a platform specific issue I can't reproduce.

Comment: turns out I *did* have a cuda-memcheck error, which didn't appear the first time for some reason